# The usage of "with of" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms

I am writing to the following sentence written by a native speaker:

> ... and build a corpus with of effective tests, reports, analyses and evaluation results.

What's really confusing me is the usage of `with of`. Isn't it more understandable, to just do this?

> ... and build a corpus with effective tests, reports, analyses and evaluation results.

Why do we need to use `with of`? And I searched it in Google and it only finds one usage. I didn't even know if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: It looks like a typo caused by writing "corpus with effective tests, reports, etc..." but then wanting to change it to "corpus of effective tests, reports, etc..." and forgetting to delete the "with." Both "with" and "of" are correct wordings, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the compound preposition(double preposition)  list in the Internet and I can't find "with of" is in the list.
There is 'with use of something', 'with help of something', etc.
I think with of isn't grammatically correct anyway.